# How to modify the directory structure of a beego project?

Tags: go, routes, directory, filepath, beego

```
bee   :1.4.1
beego :1.6.1
Go    :go version go1.6.3 windows/amd64

set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\GoSites
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
```

I am busy using the Beego framework for golang, and I am trying to modify the directory structure.

I moved the controllers, models, static, and views directories into a new directory 'app' in order to clean up the directory structure, this caused a number of routing and file path errors eg:

> can't find templatefile in the path:index.tpl

How do I modify the project to account for the changing of the directory structure without causing errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `beego.ViewsPath = "app/views"`.